# How do I get the text from a custom UITextViewCell?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm using a custom UITableViewCell that contains a UITextField. I draw this UITableViewCell in a UITableView 5 times with this code:

```
InputCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableViewIn dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"inputCell"];

[cell setUp]; //Just sets first responder and delegate.

[cell.textField setPlaceholder:[self.arrayWithFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
```

When the user have inputed data into the five cells, how do I access each of the cells data o the best way and save it?
I do not have a decleration for each cell as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag for your UITextField for each cell

```
   if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        // Add a UITextField
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        // Set a unique tag on each text field
        textField.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
        [textField release];
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        // Add a UITextField
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        // Set a unique tag on each text field
        textField.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
        [textField release];
    }
```

Comment: Does not work. How can I get these cells from another method and ask for the tag?

Comment: okay then create the global variable for textField(do not release) and use it in another method with tag.